# How to launch automatically updatedb (for locate) at startup on Debian?

Tags: locate, debian-stretch

I need to **update** manually `locate` with `sudo updatedb` before to use it, obviously!

But with "Linux Mint" for example it's done **automatically at each startup** and it's very convenient because it's enough for most of your daily searches. :o)

However I don't know how it's scheduled or how it works.

How can I convince "Debian" **to do the same**?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mlocate instead of locate:

```
sudo apt-get remove locate
sudo apt-get install mlocate
```

Comment: If I wan your place, I ask this question in [Ubuntu Ask Center](https://askubuntu.com/), not here, Stack Overflow in semi special for developers.

Comment: Forgot to say: After installation, you may wish to run /etc/cron.daily/mlocate by hand to create the database, otherwise mlocate won't work until that script is run from cron itself (since mlocate does not use the same database file as standard locate). See https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mlocate for details